# Compilation of F#/WPF code

Tags: wpf, f#

I find [some good post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2008/01/05/learning-wpf-through-f-and-vice-versa-by-john-liao.aspx) on F#/WPF programming, but it doesn't seem to teach a way to compile/build the code to make binary out of F#/WPF.

What command/tool do I use to build/compile this code into execution binary? Just running `fsc` or `fsi` doesn't seem to work.

```
#light 
#I @"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0"
#r @"WindowsBase.dll"
#r @"PresentationCore.dll"
#r @"PresentationFramework.dll"

open System
open System.Windows

(* From Chap 1 - SayHello.cs *)

let win = new Window()
win.Title <- "Say Hello"
win.Show()

#if COMPILED
[<STAThread()>]
do
     let app =  new Application() in    
     app.Run() |> ignore
#endif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to compile the code using `fsc` then you'll need to remove the `#I` and `#r` commands and use a compiler command line arguments instead. The `#light` command is not required anymore, so you can just delete first 5 lines. In addition to the `#r` references, I also had to add `System.Xaml.dll` (which is probably new in .NET 4)

Then you can compile it using something like:

```
fsc.exe -r:WindowsBase.dll -r:PresentationCore.dll -r:System.Xaml.dll
        -r:PresentationFramework.dll --target:winexe Main.fs
```

Running the code in `fsi.exe` should work just fine (after adding `#r "System.Xaml.dll"`). Just copy the code and paste it to the F# Interactive (running either in console or in Visual Studio IDE).

Answer (score 1):

Running fsc should work. You'll want to pass the --target:winexe command line argument to the fsc.exe.

See [F# Compiler Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171.aspx) for more info.